# How can I get the previous creationdate for current version in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to get the previous version creation date when querying for the current version

```
PriducID | Productversion | Productcreationdate
  100    |       1        | 5/5/2012
  100    |       2        | 6/6/2013
  100    |       3        | 7/7/2015
```

Output expecting like below

```
PriducID | Productversion | Productcreationdate
   100   |        2       | 5/5/2012
```

Comment: What version of sql server are you actually working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming correct version is 2008-r2, you need to use a sub query:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    PriducID int, 
    Productversion int, 
    Productcreationdate date
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(100, 1, '2012-05-05'),
(100, 2, '2013-06-06'),
(100, 3, '2015-07-07')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  PriducID, 
        Productversion, 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 Productcreationdate
            FROM @T t2
            WHERE t2.Productcreationdate < t1.Productcreationdate
            ORDER BY Productcreationdate DESC) As PrevProductcreationdate
FROM @T t1
WHERE Productversion = 2
```

Results:

```
PriducID    Productversion  PrevProductcreationdate
100         2               05.05.2012 00:00:00
```

If your version is 2012, you can use a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) window function to get the same result:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  PriducID, 
            Productversion, 
            LAG(Productcreationdate) OVER (ORDER BY Productcreationdate) As PrevProductcreationdate
    FROM @T
)

SELECT  PriducID, 
        Productversion, 
        PrevProductcreationdate
FROM CTE 
WHERE Productversion = 2
```